# Select if data has two instances with different values sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with multiple instances of title some hardcover (h) and some paperback (p)

```
            title            | type
-----------------------------+------
 Franklin in the Dark        | p
 Little Women                | p
 The Cat in the Hat          | p
 Dune                        | p
 The Shining                 | p
 Programming Python          | p
 Goodnight Moon              | p
 2001: A Space Odyssey       | h
 Dynamic Anatomy             | p
 Bartholomew and the Oobleck | p
 The Cat in the Hat          | h
 Dune                        | h
 The Velveteen Rabbit        | p
 The Shining                 | h
 The Tell-Tale Heart         | p
 2001: A Space Odyssey       | p
```

I'm trying to return instances that have both paper back and hardcover copies.

The table should ideally return only 4 titles.

*edit these are part of two different tables.

```
 7808 | The Shining                 |      4156 |          9
  4513 | Dune                        |      1866 |         15
  4267 | 2001: A Space Odyssey       |      2001 |         15
  1608 | The Cat in the Hat          |      1809 |          2
  1590 | Bartholomew and the Oobleck |      1809 |          2
 25908 | Franklin in the Dark        |     15990 |          2


 0385121679 |    7808 |       2 |           75 | 1993-10-01  | h
 1885418035 |     156 |       1 |          163 | 1995-03-28  | p
 0929605942 |     156 |       2 |          171 | 1998-12-01  | p
 0441172717 |    4513 |       2 |           99 | 1998-09-01  | p
 044100590X |    4513 |       3 |           99 | 1999-10-01  | h
 0451457994 |    4267 |       3 |          101 | 2000-09-12  | p
 0451198492 |    4267 |       3 |          101 | 1999-10-01  | h
 0823015505 |    2038 |       1 |           62 | 1958-01-01  | p
 0596000855 |   41473 |       2 |          113 | 2001-03-01  | p
```

Comment: use group by title and count on the type

Comment: If this is MySQL: `SELECT title FROM table GROUP BY type HAVING count(title) > 1`

Comment: Show the table column names and table names also. Also, what database is this? MySQL, MSSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple ways of doing this.  If you just want the title of the book that has both a hard cover and a paperback (I'm assuming those are the only two options).  Then you can do a query like this:

```
select title, count(*) from book group by title having count(*) > 1
```

You also could join to the table.

```
select t0.title from 
(
  select title from book where btype = 'h'
) t0 
    inner join 
(
  select title from book where btype = 'p'
) t1 on t0.title = t1.title
```

Edited for the two tables

```
select * from table_one where bookid in (
select t0.bookid
from
( 
    select bookid from table_two where type = 'h'
) t0
inner join 
(
    select bookid from table_two where type = 'p'
) t1
on t0.bookid = t1.bookid
) t2
```

Comment: Could you explain what the select's are doing, I'm having a hard time following a long but it works. Will select answer after

Comment: sure, basically I'm using a few sub queries and using the results of the subquery to further query/join.  So in the example, I'm querying "select bookid from table_two where type='h'" and assigning that as t0 then I'm querying "select bookid from table_two where type='p'" and assigning that as t1.  Once I've done that i can simply join them as i would if the subqueries were actual tables.

Answer (score 1):

This could also work.

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM BOOKS
GROUP BY TITLE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) > 1
```

Comment: This is slower then grouping by type since the title is a long string to match.

Comment: `GROUP BY TYPE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: But then you can't select the TITLE without having it in the group by clause.

Answer (score -3):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT title
FROM table a
WHERE type = 'h' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table 
              WHERE title = a.title AND
              type = 'p')
```

Comment: Extremely poor performing code, no need for a sub select for something so simple.

Comment: Maybe, but the code you suggested will break if another type is introduced, or if the same type of the same title can be entered.  Just assumptions about the constraints of the system.

Comment: Well if that is the problem then change it to the following: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IN ('h', 'p') GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) > 1`

Comment: I don't want to get into a big thing abuot this, but that code will break if there can be two paperback copies of the same title.  I heard stories of how SO can be a certain way, it's really true.

Comment: No, your code will work.  Sorry.  I just don't want to get into a big thing about it.  Have a good one.